# No such file or directory encountered trying to install Anaconda

Tags: command-line, gnome, anaconda

Spoiler: I'm still totally new to Ubuntu/Linux in general; 
In order to use GPU-supported tensorflow i tried to install Anaconda on my unix/gnome partition, following the instructions of the site: (https://www.continuum.io/downloads#linux)

(start copy from anaconda-website)

1. Download the installer
2. Optional: Verify data integrity with MD5 or SHA-256   More info
3. In your terminal window type one of the below and follow the instructions:
   Python 3.6 version

bash Anaconda3-4.3.0-Linux-x86_64.sh

(end copy from anaconda website)

Naturally i skipped part 2, opened my cmd, pasted 'bash Anaconda3-4.3.0-Linux-x86_64.sh' in there and hit enter. 
It told me: 'bash: Anaconda3-4.3.0-Linux-x86_64.sh: No such file or directory'. Now i am quite confused, sadly could not find the answer around here (probably is somewhere already, but neither googling nor searching stackoverflow gave me the result, probably am just missing the right terms to google it)

My natural guess would be that i have to tell him, where the download is, or possibly im using the wrong commandline (or something with the 'bash' is fishy), but as i said i am quite clueless.

Thank you a lot for your help in advance, 
Best regards,

Leon

Comment: If you used your browser to download it, then it will be wherever your browser saves downloaded files - usually `~/Downloads`. You can change to that directory in a terminal using `cd ~/Downloads` and then you can list the files there using `ls`.

Answer (score 2):

I got the same error, what worked for me is:
Download the Anaconda installer for linux , then change the directory to where you downloaded this installer, for me it was ~/Downloads/ ,

```
cd ~/Downloads/
```

or

```
cd /path/to/where_anaconda_installer is downloaded
```

then run the command

```
bash Anaconda3-4.3.0-Linux-x86_64.sh
```

where Anaconda3-4.3.0-Linux-x86_64.sh is the anaconda file you just downloaded

follow the screen prompts. Once installation is complete you can set the path using

```
export PATH=~/anaconda3/bin:$PATH
```

test your installation using

```
conda --version

conda --list
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
sudo ./Anaconda3-4.3.0-Linux-x86_64.sh
```

I used to install sofwares like this and it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Change permissions so bash script can be executed and than run it.

```
sudo chmod 777 Anaconda3-4.3.0-Linux-x86_64.sh
sudo ./Anaconda3-4.3.0-Linux-x86_64.sh
```

Answer (score 0):

Click [here](https://www.anaconda.com/distribution/) for detailed explanation. For short instructions, do the following (running the commands below in a terminal):

1. Download the Linux [Anaconda](https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/install/linux/) version you need.
2. Verify the downloaded data with MD5 or SHA-2, with `/path/filename` being the actual `path/filename` of the file that you downloaded:

   ```
   md5sum /path/filename # md5  
   sha256sum /path/filename # SHA-2
   ```
3. Install the Anaconda version that you downloaded:

   ```
   bash ~/Downloads/Anaconda3-2019.07-Linux-x86_64.sh # Anaconda 3.7 (latest; 2019)

   bash ~/Downloads/Anaconda2-2019.07-Linux-x86_64.sh # Anaconda 2.7
   ```
4. Scroll down by pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> on the license agreement.
5. Type `yes` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to agree to the license agreement.
6. Press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to install to the default folder.
7. Press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to this question: *Do you wish the installer to initialize Anaconda3 by running conda init?*
8. Close and reopen the terminal and type in it:

   ```
   source ~/.bashrc
   ```
9. To run `conda` from anywhere, without having the base environment activated by default, use:

   ```
   conda config --set auto_activate_base False
   ```
10. Open a terminal and type:

    ```
    anaconda-navigator
    ```

Now you can navigate Anaconda window.

Answer (score 0):

The solution sounds stupid but check the name of the file being downloaded and the command you copied.
Hope it helps